# Replace the raw text node within div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('#mydiv').html('newdiv');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">
  rawtext
  <div id="subdiv1"></div>
  <div id="subdiv2"></div>
</div>
```

I want to replace "rawtext" with a different text ("newdiv") without touching the other divs (since they are registered in javascript), so I do not want to replace the whole content of mydiv with something else but rather replace the raw text only. Can I do this with jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`.contents()` method](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) in order to access the matched elements and text nodes.

From there, you would just access the first text node and change the [`textContent` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent):

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/wkc4vLth/)

```
$('#mydiv').contents().first()[0].textContent = 'Replaced text node text.';
```

Comment: ok, and what if "rawtext"  was empty from the very beginning, so that 'Replaced text node text' has to be inserted?

Comment: @Ferenjito Your question is about *replacing* text.. But if there aren't any text nodes or whitespace characters to replace, you would have to prepend the text - [see this example](http://jsfiddle.net/j9ahwyty/). If there **is** whitespace, then it would [still work](http://jsfiddle.net/kzxjhhn2/).